# Nginx Rewrite For Specific Directory

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

How to rewrite only for specific directory in Nginx?

Public folder contain static html file (I don't want to rewite here), rewrite url for dashboard directory

Example:

public
  -Index.html
  -page2.html
  -pahe3.html
  -dashboard <-- this directory to rewrite

At the end, we can access url like this:
http://example.com/index.html or http://example.com/dashboard/home

i try to add this:

```
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

index index.php index.html index.htm;
set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html';
root $root_path;

location /dashboard {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    set $root_path '/usr/share/nginx/html/dashboard/public';
    root $root_path;



    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index /index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
        #fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    location ~* ^/(css|img|js|flv|swf|download)/(.+)$ {
        root $root_path;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }   
}

try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?_url=/$1;
}
```

But not working. It show page not found

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/